# Push notifications

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, push

i'm deveoloping an app in android, where you can sign up to recieve push notifications.
I have problems to show the notifications in my phone, i made the registration, with google, i recive the code and store the results in a mysql database, in php i send the notification, with success, i recieve this message:

```
{"multicast_id":6686183359185983221,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1443999101817727%7f187d75f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

but i recieve nothing in my phone, this is the code of my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.worldsoccermanager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<!-- Needs internet to connect to Google Services -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Google Services requires a Google account -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate when receive a notification -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!-- Lets app receive data messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission using "signature" so that only this app 
     can read the messages returned by GCM
         - YOUR_PACKAGE is your product's package name. E.g. com.example.test -->
<permission
     android:name="it.worldsoccermanager.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
     android:name="it.worldsoccermanager.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TeamHomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_team_home" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notification"
            android:parentActivityName=".TeamHomeActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="it.worldsoccermanager.TeamHomeActivity" />
        </activity>

<receiver
            android:name=".NotificationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="it.worldsoccermanager" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and this is my code to recieve notifications:

```
package tools;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import android.R;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public NotificationReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty())
        {
 //Commentato da me
           /* if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType))
            {*/

                // emette una notifica sul dispositivo
                sendNotification(context,messageType);

           // }
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(Context ctx,String msg)
    {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // scelta suoneria per notifica
        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setContentTitle("WSM - WorldSoccerManager")
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setSound(sound);

        // effettua la notifica
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the permission on the receiver.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".NotificationReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="it.worldsoccermanager" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: No, this was the clear error to see. Is it still not working?

Comment: i can only see this evening cause now i'm at work and here i can't try, i've said that, because i think i have made a try with the modification you say.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll try, and hope it's the solution, i'm going crazy!

Comment: I don't realy know what is the problem now! Are you sure about the registeration id and you have initialized the app at google console correctly?

Comment: problem solved, it was the WI-FI router it was blocking incoming messages.

Comment: Whaaaat! That's realy bad.